# Run time error reverse a string

Tags: c++, string, runtime-error, reverse

I know return end is not correct, I am thinking about to use one of my pointer to go to the end, and then go back by the size of the string to return the reversed string. Is there a more efficient way of doing that? Also, more importantly, am I getting a run time error here? http://ideone.com/IzvhmW

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string Reverse(char * word)
{
    char *end = word;
    while(*end)
        ++end;
    --end;

    char tem;
    while(word < end) {
             tem = *word;
             *word = *end;
             *end = tem;  //debug indicated the error at this line

             ++word;
             --end;
    }

    return end;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    string s = Reverse("piegh");
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just read the error messages of your compiler! `x.cpp:27:31: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]` The warning is activated without even specifying -Wall.

Comment: Indeed. Warnings exist for a purpose and should never be ignored! This warning should have certainly been provided as part of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing "piegh" to Reverse, which gets converted to a pointer to char. That pointer to char points into a read only string literal. Perhaps you meant to copy the string literal "piegh" before attempting to assign to it:

```
char fubar[] = "piegh";
string s = Reverse(fubar);
```

After all, how could you justify `"piegh"[0] = "peigh"[4];`?

Answer (score -1):

What does this part of your code do?
  `while(*end)
       ++end; //Assuming you are moving your pointer to hold the last character but not sure y
--end;` //y this one
`while(word < end)`// also i am not sure how this works

This code works and serves the same purpose

```
    char* StrReverse(char* str)
{
int i, j, len;
char temp;
char *ptr=NULL;
i=j=len=temp=0;

len=strlen(str);
ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
ptr=strcpy(ptr,str);
for (i=0, j=len-1; i<=j; i++, j--)
{
    temp=ptr[i];
    ptr[i]=ptr[j];
    ptr[j]=temp;
}
return ptr;
}
```

Comment: It's also unnecessarily sloppy: `strlen` returns a `size_t` yet `len` is an `int` (which could cause this code to malfunction), `sizeof (char)` is *always* 1 so there is no need to multiply `len+1` by it, `temp` is declared in a most inelegant location at the top of StrReverse rather than the loop it is used in, and the code forces the caller to manage memory by using `free` (storage duration should be the caller's choice, for obvious simplicity and performance benefits)... Once these issues are resolved, there would be a number of unnecessary variables; This code is overly complex.